# Locked out of AWS EC2 Instance - forgot ssh root password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I log into my AWS EC2 instance via ssh, all of a sudden I'm being given this error:

> -bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied

Super annoying, and it appears as though somehow permissions have been changed (accidentally), and I can't get back in. That said, I've tried logging in as root user vs. ec2-user, but I can't seem to remember the password I set for user root.

How can I recover this password or reset it without root user access? Help!

Comment: You'll probably need to stop this instance, detach the EBS volume, start another EC2 instance, mount the volume to the new instance and correct the permissions that way. Once done, mount the volume back to the original instance and start it up. AWS has a somewhat outdated guide for this scenario: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/how-to-recover-an-unreachable-linux-instance/

Comment: Ugh. Isn't there a way for me to create another user (other than ec2-user) with root permissions from the ec2 dashboard or something? @MattHealy

Comment: No you can't, the solution provided by @MattHealy is the right one

Comment: @QuentinRevel I've created an Image of my currently running instance - if I detach the volume, does it delete everything on the instance? :/ Seems risky lol

Comment: You can't detach root EBS volume, you need to shutdown the instance first

Comment: @MattHealy Attempting your answer, but AWS doesnt seem to let me choose/change my Availability Zone anymore? And I can't remount the volume to a new instance unless it's launched in the same Zone?

Comment: What kind of AMI are you using? If it has the SSM agent installed you can use session manager to get onto the instance through the console with a user that has root privileges much like ec2-user at which point you might be able to fix this issue.

Comment: Was finally able to accomplish this via your suggestion @MattHealy - what a process O_O thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By default, root user login is disabled on EC2 instances, as documented here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-change-root-linux/

So, unless you explicitly enabled SSH root login, there is no point in trying to find out the root password.

However, ec2-user should be a sudo user itself, try executing

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/profile
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the following errors: sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin